# Rxbag is not publishing

Tags: ros, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I've recorded a bag file useing *rxbag --record -a -o all.bag*.

When I want to play it I run *rxbag all_2011_12_09_10_10_20.bag* and the rxbag window opens and I can play, see the graphics, everithing. But it is not publishing the data to rostopics. What do I need to do?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12282/rxbag-is-not-publishing/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rxbag only publishes to topics that you explicitly select. Right-click on the topics list in the rxbag window and choose the topics you're interested in (or "Publish All") in the "Publish..." popup menu.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Osswald](https://answers.ros.org/users/1042/stefan-osswald/) with karma: 281 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2011-12-08**:
Thank you wery much, you solved it!